# Is there a JavaScript code to open the downloaded file from any browser?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS code which should download a file and need to open that corresponding file. I'm able to download it but need a JavaScript code to open the recently downloaded file from any browser.

Comment: downloaded suggests the file saved on the client computer - no, you can't do that

Comment: One possible error message: "Not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: Short answer is **No**. This will need a server side language.

Comment: Sounds fun: Download "total-virus-fun.exe" and execute :-D
with a selfwritten browser plugin this should be possible

Answer (score 2):

**Answer is No.**

**Why :**

When user download file into his local file system then downloaded file became a part of users file and as you know you can't access any file/directory from users local file system.

**Alternative solution :Yes**

1. Download file using XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) into blob object [help link](http://usefulangle.com/post/68/javascript-ajax-download-file)
2. Open file from saved blob object.

in above alternative solution You can also allow use to save file(download file).